# Why isn't this foreach loop working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I created a class entity and I'm trying to fill one of it's properties using arrays, in the following way:

```
Usuario[] arrayusers = new Usuario[contador];
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    arrayusers[i].Celular = dr["CELULAR"].ToString();
    i++;
}
```

And it's returning the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Why is that?

I tried changing my created class for a string array and it worked...

```
string[] stringx = new string[contador];
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    stringx[i] = dr["CELULAR"].ToString();
    i++;
}
```

It's for an IT term paper!

Comment: A metaphor might be a 3 ring binder (an array) that CAN hold 300 pieces of paper.  You still have to buy (create) the paper in the binder to write on.

Comment: can you try debugging it with breakpoint and see what's null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only defined an array `arrayusers`, all its elements are set to null. You have to instantiate each array item:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    arraysers[i] = new Usuario(); //<<<<<<<<<<  here
    arrayusers[i].Celular = dr["CELULAR"].ToString();
    i++;
}
```

> Why it worked with string array?

Because you are not accessing any property/method of the element. Instead you are assigning it a new string item in the loop. Before entering the loop it was null. Try something like:

```
string[] stringx = new string[contador];
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(stringx[i].Length); //<<<< Exception here
    stringx[i] = dr["CELULAR"].ToString();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: So: I was trying to assign value to a property of an element that was null, right? Hence the error message... I got it! Thank you, Habib.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `arrayusers` and that `dt.Rows` are the same size?  Also I don't see where you are initializing `arrayusers[i]` it would be `null` until after it was assigned.

Should probably be something like:

```
Usario tmp = new Usario();
tmp.Celular = dr["CELULAR"].ToString();
arrayUsers[i] = tmp;
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess the first line of my code wasn't enough for instantiating the array... thanks!